# Alarm service is not fired

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I want to set alarm at particular time with hour and minute.

I am trying to do it this way:

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
alarm (AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calAlarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

But alarm is not fired at particular hour and minute.

I have seen many example on `stackoverflow` and other blogs, but that also didn't work for me.

Comment: What is a version of device?

Comment: For 2 version 6.0 and 7.0

Comment: Did you try start your app in version 5.0 and earlier?

Comment: No. i haven't try it.

Comment: Just try in version 5.0. It seems like problem in something like Doze Mode... If not, just try make alarm by doc example

Comment: i dont think its doze mode problem. As i am running app from android studio and set 1 minute later time.

Comment: [Scheduling Repeating Alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android 6.0 (API level 23), Android introduces Doze feature that extend battery life for users by managing how apps behave when a device is not connected to a power source.

Doze is particularly likely to affect activities that AlarmManager alarms and timers manage, because alarms in Android 5.1 (API level 22) or lower do not fire when the system is in Doze.

To help with scheduling alarms, Android 6.0 (API level 23) introduces two new AlarmManager methods: setAndAllowWhileIdle() and setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(). With these methods, you can set alarms that will fire even if the device is in Doze.

**Note:** Neither setAndAllowWhileIdle() nor setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() can fire alarms more than once per 9 minutes, per app.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmPeriodicTime, pendingIntent);

} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmPeriodicTime, pendingIntent);

} else {
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmPeriodicTime, pendingIntent);
}
```

More info:
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
AlarmManagerCompat.setAlarmClock(alarmManager, time, triggerIntent, showIntent)
```

You can find the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/AlarmManagerCompat.html#setalarmclock).